# instabot failed to upload picture in python

Tags: python, automation

i tried automated uploading with this code:

```
from instabot import Bot
bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="#CENCORED#",password="#CENCORED#")

bot.upload_photo("kuva.png",caption="juo sitä kahvii")
```

and i got this error message:

```
"C:\Users\sever\ig automation\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/sever/ig automation/main.py"
2021-09-13 16:03:19,103 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2021-09-13 16:03:19,104 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2021-09-13 16:03:22,719 - INFO - Logged-in successfully as 'severi_hirvonen'!
2021-09-13 16:03:22,720 - INFO - LOGIN FLOW! Just logged-in: True
FOUND: w:1086 h:1080 r:1.0055555555555555
2021-09-13 16:03:43,625 - ERROR - Photo Upload failed with the following response: <Response [400]>
2021-09-13 16:03:43,626 - INFO - Photo 'kuva.png' is not uploaded.
2021-09-13 16:03:43,631 - INFO - Total requests: 31

Process finished with exit code 0
```

i followed this tutorial perfectly until this point i think: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyEIihDoXR8

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly because instagramm detects bots and do not let them upload picures.